# How can I reclassify a raster by zone?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, qgis-2.8, reclassify

I have a raster layer of a river network containing weighted flow accumulation values and a raster layer of lakes (see image bellow). I want to replace the values of all the river pixel that fall into the lake by 0. **How can I reclassify a raster by zone?**

[image]

I tried to achieve the same result by doing this :

1. Use the *Extract by Mask* to have a layer of the river network that fall into the lakes.
2. Use the *Raster Calculator* to subtract the raster layer of the river network by the raster layer of the river network that fall into the lakes.

I though this would give the pixels that fall into the lakes the value of 0, but ALL the pixels get the value of 0 whether the pixel falls into a lake or not.

I have tried with ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS 2.8.2 with the same result, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reclass the lake layer to (0) lake, and (1) Everywhere else that covers the entire river layer (union).

Multiply (times) this output by your rivers.

Comment: payback for answering my question earlier'